# std::get does not forward rvalue-reference for std::apply

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue-reference, stdtuple, stdapply

I am wondering why `std::apply` does not forward `rvalue-reference` when working with reference types in tuples (see [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/56a8NAr8nVKxQ6Q7)):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
void assertRvalueReference(T&& t)
{   
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(t)>, "Ups"); 
}

int main()
{
    struct A{};
    A a;
    int v;
    auto t = std::tuple<A&&, int>(std::move(a), v); // essentially `std::forward_as_tuple(v, std::move(a))`

    std::apply([](auto&& arg, ...)
               {
                   assertRvalueReference(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg)); 
               }, std::move(t));

    std::apply([](auto&& arg, ...)
               {
                   // assertRvalueReference(arg); // This should in my opinion not fail
               }, t);

    assertRvalueReference(non_std_get<0>(t)); 
}
```

The root cause for this is `std::get` and the reference collapsing rule.
Wouldn't it make more sense if `std::apply` internally  would use this `non_std_get`

```cpp
template<std::size_t Index, typename Tuple>
constexpr decltype(auto) non_std_get(Tuple&& t)
{
    using Type = std::tuple_element_t<Index, std::remove_cvref_t<Tuple>>;
    if constexpr(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<Type>)
    {
        return std::move(std::get<Index>(t));
    }
    else
    {
        return std::get<Index>(t);
    }
}
```

which would result in a perfect forward for

```cpp
std::apply([](auto&& arg){/*arg is here `int&&`*/}, t);
```

Comment: An rrvalue--reference is an lvalue. To make it behave differently in this specific case would be confusing.

Comment: Thats true, but for what use is the `std::apply(t,...)`  `int a;  auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(a, A{})` when its not doing a perfect forward, meaning the lambda should get a `rvalue-reference = A&&` (which it does not, it gets a `A&`)

Comment: It makes sense to me since passing an rvalue-reference to a function is in fact passing an lvalue to a function. I don't want code to magically do hiddens things for me without me telling it to do so. In that case I would prefer a `apply_with_forwarding` to be able to be explicit in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `std::apply`, it is in your lambda.

Inside your lambda, `arg` is *always* an lvalue. You need to explicitly cast it to an rvalue with `std::forward` in order to make it an rvalue.

Comment: your statement is clear to me, the real issue is in `std::get` which returns a `A&` if the **lvalue** tuple contains a type `A&&`  = rvalue-reference.